# spark flume streaming scala foreachpartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flume, spark-streaming

I am trying to process events from a flume-avro sink via spark streaming and am doing it in the way [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams), but for what ever reason the code does not execute where is says "DOES NOT WORK".  The partion.size() is returning 1, but its like it doesn't even iterate that 1 partition.  ps I'm a scala noob.

```
  events.foreachRDD { rdd =>
if (rdd.take(1).size == 1) {
  System.out.println("**********************************WE GOT AN RDD")
  System.out.println("*******************************NUM PARTITIONS =" + rdd.partitions.size)
  val array = rdd.collect()
  array.foreach { x => 
    System.out.println("**************WORKS********************" + new String(x.event.getBody().array(),"UTF-8"))
  }
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionItr =>
    //System.out.println("**********************************WE NEVER GET HERE " + partitionItr.size)
    //create db connection from pool
    //val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionItr.foreach { item =>
      //write to db
      System.out.println("****************DOES NOT WORK******************" + new String(item.event.getBody().array(),"UTF-8"))
      //return connection to pool
      //ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)
    }
  }
  //rdd.count()
}else{
  System.out.println("**********************************WE GOT NOTHIN")
}
```

}